# awk need epoch days logic for data transformation

Tags: awk

In excel when I give in the cell A1=1/1/1970 and A2=today(), A2 resolves to 17-Apr-2020.
And when I subtract A2 with A1, I get 18369 which is the epoch days for my data transformation logic.

I'm trying to simulate the same functionality in awk, but not getting the whole number

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { t=strftime("%F",systime()); print t; gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0" ); print t2/(24*60*60) } '
2020-04-17
18368.8
$
```

Is this translation for awk correct?. What is the reason for 0.2 difference in my awk code. How to fix it.

Comment: Try `utc-flag` i.e. `awk 'BEGIN {t=strftime("%F",systime(), 1); print t; gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0", 1); print t2/(24*60*60) } '`

Comment: @anubhava.. no it throws invalid number of arguments for mktime error.. removing that 1, I get  18367.8

Comment: GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: I have `GNU Awk 5.0.1` and `awk 'BEGIN {t=strftime("%F",systime()); print t; gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0", 1); print t2/(24*60*60) } '` works fine.

Comment: @anubhava.. so is this a bug in lower version?. what is the workaround for my case

Comment: Try this: `TZ=UTC awk 'BEGIN {t=strftime("%F",systime()); print t; gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0"); print t2/(24*60*60) } '`

Comment: yes.. it works, now I get 18368 and 2020-04-16. I'm in India IST - 01:40 AM now, so excel gives 17 Apr. The offset might be the issue for 0.2 less, i guess.

Comment: @anubhava.. thank you.. could you pls add it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You are seeing this difference due to timezone offset between your current local timezone and UTC.

On more recent `gnu awk` version you can use this to pass an additional `utc-flag` to `mktime` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN {t=strftime("%F",systime()); print t;
     gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0", 1); print t2/(24*60*60)}'
```

However if you are on older awk versions then use this work-around to get time computations in `UTC`:

```
TZ=UTC awk 'BEGIN {t=strftime("%F",systime()); print t;
gsub("-"," ",t); t2=mktime(t " 0 0 0"); print t2/(24*60*60) } '
```

Answer (score 1):

The epoch days involve calculating how many multiples of "86400" seconds have passed since 1-Jan-1970. We have a boundary issue in this calculation, i.e we should not take 1st Jan, 1970 as 1 epoch day because the particular day has not completed.

That is the reason the java epoch days function returns 0 for 1-Jan-1970

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse("1970-01-01").toEpochDay
res2: Long = 0
```

Now, with this for 17-Apr-2020, we get

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse("2020-04-17").toEpochDay
res3: Long = 18369
```

Let's try to get the same answer using awk.

```
awk -v dt="2020-04-17" ' 
 function epoch_days(dta) 
 {  
    yr=dta[0]; 
    for(i=1970;i<strftime("%Y",mktime(dta[1] " 12 31 0 0 0"));i++) 
    e1+=strftime("%j",mktime(i " 12 31 0 0 0"))+0; 
    e1+=strftime("%j",mktime(dta[1] " " dta[2] " " dta[3] " 0 0 0"))-1; 
    return e1 
  } 
  BEGIN {
  split(dt,dta,"-"); 
  print epoch_days(dta) ;
  }'

18369
```

Lets cross verify for current date i.e 22-Aug-2021

```
java.time.LocalDate.now
res5: java.time.LocalDate = 2021-08-22
java.time.LocalDate.now.toEpochDay
res6: Long = 18861
```

And our awk code returns

```
awk  ' 
 function epoch_days(dta) 
 {  
    yr=dta[0]; 
    for(i=1970;i<strftime("%Y",mktime(dta[1] " 12 31 0 0 0"));i++) 
    e1+=strftime("%j",mktime(i " 12 31 0 0 0"))+0; 
    e1+=strftime("%j",mktime(dta[1] " " dta[2] " " dta[3] " 0 0 0"))-1; 
    return e1 
  } 
  BEGIN {
  dt=systime(); # 22-Aug-2021
  dt2=strftime("%F",dt);
  split(dt2,dta,"-"); 
  print epoch_days(dta) ;
  }'

  18861
```

Comment: ++ for your solution but wouldn't `awk 'BEGIN{ print int(systime()/86400) }'` do the same?